# Как дождаться окончания установки состояния с помощью хука useState

Tags: reactjs, хук, react-hook

Всем привет! Столкнулся с тем, что после установки состояния с помощью хука. Обновление происходит не сразу. Как дождаться окончания установки состояния при использовании хука useState?

```
const AvailableLanguages = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [activeLanguages, setActiveLanguages] = useState(["RU"])
  const [addDialogActive, setAddDialogActive] = useState(false)

  const addLanguage = (language) => {
    const currentLanguages = activeLanguages
    if (!currentLanguages.includes(language)) {
      currentLanguages.push(language)
      setActiveLanguages(currentLanguages)

      // TODO: onChange(activeLanguages)
    }
  }

  const removeLanguage = (language) => {
    const filteredLangs = activeLanguages.filter(lang => lang != language)
    setActiveLanguages(filteredLangs)

    // TODO: onChange(activeLanguages)
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: использовать ещё один хук - `useEffect`

Comment: ок, спасибо) так и сделал. Надеюсь правильно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так) Работает. Надеюсь, что правильно)

```
const AvailableLanguages = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [activeLanguages, setActiveLanguages] = useState(["RU"])
  const [addDialogActive, setAddDialogActive] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(activeLanguages)
  }, [activeLanguages])

  const addLanguage = (language) => {
    setActiveLanguages(currentLanguages => {
      let langs = [...currentLanguages]
      if (!currentLanguages.includes(language)) {
        langs.push(language)
      }
      return langs
    })
  }

  const removeLanguage = (language) => {
    setActiveLanguages(currentLanguages => {
      return currentLanguages.filter(lang => lang != language)
    })
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Лучше написать так:

useEffect(() => {
    onChange(activeLanguages)
  }, activeLanguages)

Так как в вашем случае ссылка на массив будет каждый раз новая и хук будет срабатывать всегда.